# On uniform randomness of the weight of the remaining edges of a graph after deleting some of them

Tags: algorithms, graphs, randomness

Suppose we have a graph $G(V,E,W)$, where $V$ and $E$ are the set of vertices and edges and $W$ is non-negative weight on the edges. Let $w(e)$ be the weight of edge $e$ and $N(e)$ be the neighboring edges of $e$. An edge $e$ is locally subdominant if its weight is smaller than all of its neighbors. With this background Let we have the following algorithm,

```
for e in E 
if w(e) is locally sub-dominant 
    delete e from the graph G
    double weights of all e in  N(e)
```

My question is after this loop ends what can we say about uniform randomness of the remaining edges. Are they still uniform random?

Comment: What do you mean by "uniform randomness"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us consider the simplest case, that of a path of length two edges, which are drawn uniformly and independently from $[0,1]$. Let us suppose that the first edge is sub-dominant, which happens with probability 1/2. The probability that the weight of second edge is at most $t \in [0,1]$ is
$$
\Pr[x \leq y \leq t \mid x \leq y] = \Pr[x,y \leq t] = t^2.
$$
Here $x$ is the weight of the first edge, and $y$ is the weight of the second edge. We see that even before doubling, the distribution of $y$ is non-uniform.

Next, let us examine the case of a star with three edges, again drawn uniformly and independently from $[0,1]$. Again suppose that the first edge is sub-dominant, which happens with probability 1/3. The probability that the weight of the second edge is at most $t \in [0,1]$ while that of the third edge is at most $u \in [0,1]$ is
$$
\Pr[y \leq t, z \leq u \mid x \leq y,z] =
3 \int_0^{\min(t,u)} (t-x)(u-x) \, dx = \\
3tum - \frac{3}{2}(t+u)m^2 + m^3.
$$
Here $x,y,z$ are the weights of the first, second, and third edges, respectively, and $m = \min(t,u)$. Substituting $u = 1$, we obtain
$$
\Pr[y \leq t \mid x \leq y,z] = \frac{3t^2-t^3}{2}.
$$
Calculation shows that for generic $t,u$,
$$
\Pr[y \leq t, z \leq u \mid x \leq y,z] \neq
\Pr[y \leq t \mid x \leq y,z] \Pr[z \leq u \mid x \leq y,z],
$$
that is, the remaining weights are no longer independent.

Comment: But what if we create two separate subgraphs as follows. We take the least k weight edges (say F) of G and make a subgraph, G[F] spanning these edges. We run the above algorithm on top of that. Note that when the algorithm runs on G[F] some of the edges not in F can be doubled as these neighboring edges may not be part of F. Now can we argue that the weight of the remaining edges i.e., E-F are uniformly distributed among themselves?

Comment: Probably doesn’t help.